# Simulating an one-sample t-test in r

Tags: r

i am trying to conduct one-sample t-test in R.

Based on my code here, t should be -4.979296:

```
sample.mean = 20
population.mean = 40
sd = 11
n = 30              
t <- (sample.mean-population.mean)/(sd/sqrt(n))
```

However, when i run

```
test <- c(rnorm(30, mean = 20, sd = 11))
t.test(test, mu = 40)
```

it doesn't provide me the same t-score.

can you tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: wow it works like a charm.. thank u...

Comment: Since you are sampling from a random variable, the sampling distribution will only have a mean of 20 and a SD of 11 on average.

Answer (score 1):

`rnorm` generates random deviates every time and average of the generated values will be fairly close to the `mean` specified but not exactly same. If you store the generated values in a variable and do the computation, you will see that both values are same. I will also use `set.seed()` so that the example becomes reproducible for everyone.

```
set.seed(42)
test <- c(rnorm(30, mean = 20, sd = 11))
t.test(test, mu = 40)

#   One Sample t-test

#data:  test
#t = -7.6356, df = 29, p-value = 2.031e-08
#alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 40
#95 percent confidence interval:
# 15.59947 25.90944
#sample estimates:
#mean of x 
# 20.75446 

mean(test)
#[1] 20.75446  #NOTE THIS IS CLOSE TO 20 BUT NOT 20

(mean(test)-40)/(sd(test)/sqrt(30)) 
#[1] -7.635627
```